# differentiating a String-list and a String[]-list with a single element

Tags: java, casting

I'm building lists using Arrays.asList. Sometimes String lists, and sometimes String[] lists.

Now I guess that the problem arises with trying to differentiate a String-list built from a String[], and a string[]-list with a single String[].

Of course the problem wouldn't be nice if I didn't have to cast to Object and back.

Here is a little snippet to clarify what happens:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    System.out.println("l1 "+l1);
    System.out.println("String.class.isInstance(l1.get(0)) : "+String.class.isInstance(l1.get(0)));
    List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList(new String [] {"a", "b", "c"});
    System.out.println("l2 "+l2);
    System.out.println("String.class.isInstance(l2.get(0)) : "+String.class.isInstance(l2.get(0)));
    List<String[]> l3 = Arrays.asList(new String [] {"a", "b", "c"}, new String [] {"a", "b", "c"});
    System.out.println("l3 "+l3);
    System.out.println("String.class.isInstance(l3.get(0)) : "+String.class.isInstance(l3.get(0)));
    //List<String[]> l4 = Arrays.asList(new String [] {"a", "b", "c"});
    Object l4 = Arrays.asList(new String [] {"a", "b", "c"});
    System.out.println("l4 "+l4);
    System.out.println("String.class.isInstance(l4.get(0)) : "+String.class.isInstance(((List<String[]>)l4).get(0)));
}
```

The output is:

```
l1 [a, b, c]
String.class.isInstance(l1.get(0)) : true
l2 [a, b, c]
String.class.isInstance(l2.get(0)) : true
l3 [[Ljava.lang.String;@15db9742, [Ljava.lang.String;@6d06d69c]
String.class.isInstance(l3.get(0)) : false
l4 [a, b, c]
String.class.isInstance(l4.get(0)) : true
```

Look closely at the last line: l4 was built as an object, but surely as a String-list. However, trying to cast to String[]-list passes compilation and execution. Until of course I would try to use the String as a String[].

2 questions:
- shouldn't last line blow at runtime?
- how should I change l4 initialization to get a String[]-list with a single item?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that the comment line would fail, so this is not a way to force a String[]-list..

Comment: the answer to the second part, was easy :      Object l5 = Arrays.asList(new String [][] {{"a", "b", "c"}});
  System.out.println("l5 "+l5);
  System.out.println("String.class.isInstance(l5.get(0)) : "+String.class.isInstance(((List<String[]>)l5).get(0)));
  System.out.println("l5.get(0) : "+Arrays.toString(((List<String[]>)l5).get(0)));

Comment: "shouldn't last line blow at runtime?" Why should it?

Comment: Yet another erasure question. Google `Java erasure` and read up.

Comment: @user2357112 : I don't get it. isn't erasure about late guessing of generic type ? so that would be the case for something like "Object l4 = Arrays.asList();" where indeed you don't need to specify the generic of the list. But here, the initialization gets very specific as to make l4 a String-list

Comment: @CKing because "(List<String[]>)l4"  and l4 is a String-list from "l4 = Arrays.asList(new String [] {"a", "b", "c"})". or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things going on here.

> shouldn't last line blow at runtime?

Well, no, since the JVM has no idea about the *parameterized type*: `List<String[]>`, all it knows is the given reference can be *downcast* at runtime and since indeed it can do that (it *is* a `List` after all) and since the zeroth element is a string, it happily dereferences it and calls `.toString()` on it.

It's the `javac` compiler that is trying to tell you that you are doing something that *may not be* type-safe. If you compiled the last line, `javac` gives you the following warning on that line:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
    System.out.println("String.class.isInstance(l4.get(0)) : " + 
String.class.isInstance(((List<String[]>) l4).get(0)));                                                                                                            
  ^
  required: List<String[]>
  found:    Object
```

JVM always gives you an *unchecked cast* warning when you are trying to cast a reference to a *parameterized type*.

Also note that the method `asList` is a (so-called) *varargs* method. The array that you are passing is treated as a sequence of multiple parameters.

Don't do this (mixing of arrays and lists).

> how should I change l4 initialization to get a String[]-list with a single item?

```
    List<String[]> l5 = new ArrayList<>();
    l5.add(new String[]{"a", "b", "c"});
    System.out.println("String[].class.isInstance(l5.get(0)) : " + 
    String[].class.isInstance(l5.get(0)));
```

prints:

```
String[].class.isInstance(l5.get(0)) : true
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to answer the first question here, since it's been answered many times before. But as for you second question of how to pass a single `String[]` element to `Arrays.asList()`, I can think of 2 solutions.

1. Explicitly initialize a 2-dimensional array with a single outer element:

   ```
   List<String[]> l4 = Arrays.asList(new String[][] {{"a", "b", "c"}})
   ```
2. Call the method with an explicit type parameter, so the compiler knows to interpret your argument as a single element:

   ```
   List<String[]> l4 = Arrays.<String[]>asList(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"})
   ```